# jQuery - if element after another element contains text remove

Tags: jquery

Suppose this code:

```
<pre>
  <div class="wp-caption"></div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</pre>
```

I would like to check if after a `<div>` with class `wp-caption` there is a `<p>` with `nbsp;`. If there is, remove it.

My attempt:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if ( $( 'div.wp-caption' ).next().is( "p:contains('&nbsp;')" ) ) {
        $( "p" ).remove( ":contains('&nbsp;')" );
    }
});
```

Comment: `$( "p" ).remove( ":contains('&nbsp;')" );` removes all `<p>` elements that contain `&nbsp;`, not just the ones that are after `div.wp-caption`.

Comment: makes sense, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the answer of Barmar, this can even be accomplished by a one liner:

```
$('div.wp-caption').next("p:contains('&nbsp;')").remove();
```

There is not really a need to loop before, because the selector applies on every element by default.

```js
$('div.wp-caption').next("p:contains('&nbsp;')").remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
  <div class="wp-caption"></div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</pre>

<pre>
  <div class="wp-caption"></div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</pre>

<pre>
  <div class="wp-caption"></div>
  <p>test</p>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks! element containing &nbsp couldn't be selected, just had to replace it with \u00a0. seems text here ->contains("this text") doesn't need to be quoted. $('div.wp-caption').next("p:contains(\u00a0)").remove();

Answer (score 2):

Use `.each()` to loop over all the `div.wp-caption` elements, and remove the next element if it matches the `:contains()` criteria.

```
$('div.wp-caption').each(function() {
    $(this).next("p:contains('&nbsp;')").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the title I didn't specify the text to be contained is the HTML code "&nbsp"
which couldn't be selected straightforward but had to be replaced with "\u00a0"
Both answers where right, just that details. Thanks!

```
$('div.wp-caption').next("p:contains(\u00a0)").remove();
```